# New Lines in HTML

Tags: html

I am curious as to how browsers interpret line breaks in HTML and how this translates into white space in the rendered markup.  For example consider the following two divs:

```
<div>
    <select>
        <option>one</option>
    </select>
    <input />
</div>
<div>
    <select>
        <option>one</option>
    </select><input />
</div>
```

The first div will have more white space between the select and input elements because the line break between them is being rendered into white space; seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rpf3/FSnhH/1/).  I am curious as to the reason behind this and what the best method to avoid this extra spacing while maintaining readable HTML is as I do not feel that the second div is very readable.

Comment: If at least one white-space character appears between two HTML elements in the HTML source code, the browser will create a *TextNode* between those two elements in the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any whitespace in html, including 40 empty characters, will be interpretted as one `' '` character.  So a line break and 500 spaces will still display as one space.  The best way to avoid the spacing is with css:

```
select{float:left}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FSnhH/4/

Comment: Yeah floating the select would fix this, it just seems like a weird thing to have to do.  I noticed it when I went to append a third div created in JavaScript and the rendered white space was different

Comment: You wouldn't have to float necessarily... just use css to format your rendered/generated html

Comment: How could CSS besides float deal with the fact that there is a rendered text node in between the elements?

Comment: @rpf3 - `word-spacing` and `letter-spacing` are sometimes used, See http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/ for a run-down of the most common solutions.